# PIC18F2550 Memory game PIC C18 programming LED off

Tags: c, memory, puzzle, pic, pic18

I am using MPLAB C18 compiler to write c code for a PIC18F2550 which is to control a memory game. The user is to repeat a sequence of flashing LEDs by pressing corresponding buttons. A bit like a old Simon game but with a sequence just happening once.

I have been struggling so far and I have only managed to get a number of LEDs to turn on, but the buttons only turn off the LEDs for a split second then they go on again.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <p18f2550.h>
#include <delays.h>

//#pragma config WDT = OFF //Disable watchdog timer

// LED Configuration
#define LED_PIN_0 LATAbits.LATA0 //RA0
#define LED_PIN_1 LATAbits.LATA1 //RA1
#define LED_PIN_2 LATAbits.LATA2 //RA2
#define LED_PIN_3 LATAbits.LATA3 //RA3
#define LED_PIN_4 LATAbits.LATA4 //RA4
#define LED_PIN_5 LATAbits.LATA5 //RA5
#define LED_PIN_6 LATAbits.LATA6 //RA6

// Push Button Configuration
#define PUSH_BUTTON_0 PORTBbits.RB0 //RB0
#define PUSH_BUTTON_1 PORTBbits.RB1 //RB1
#define PUSH_BUTTON_2 PORTBbits.RB2 //RB2
#define PUSH_BUTTON_3 PORTBbits.RB3 //RB3
#define PUSH_BUTTON_4 PORTBbits.RB4 //RB4
#define PUSH_BUTTON_5 PORTBbits.RB5 //RB5
#define PUSH_BUTTON_6 PORTBbits.RB6 //RB6

// Global Variables
int led_array[7] ; // array storing the pin outs
int button_array[7] ;

void main()
{
int i;
ADCON1 = 0b11111111;
TRISA = 0; // sets the LED pins to output
TRISB = 1; // sets pushbutton pins to input

PORTA = 0;
PORTB = 0;

//sequence
led_array[0] = 1 ;
led_array[1] = 0 ;
led_array[2] = 1 ;
led_array[3] = 0 ;
led_array[4] = 1 ;
led_array[5] = 1 ;
led_array[6] = 0 ;


// Configure the LEDs
LED_PIN_0 = led_array[0] ;
LED_PIN_1 = led_array[1] ;
LED_PIN_2 = led_array[2] ;
LED_PIN_3 = led_array[3] ;
LED_PIN_4 = led_array[4] ;
LED_PIN_5 = led_array[5] ;
LED_PIN_6 = led_array[6] ;


// Configure the push button array
PUSH_BUTTON_0 = button_array[0] ;
PUSH_BUTTON_1 = button_array[1] ;
PUSH_BUTTON_2 = button_array[2] ;
PUSH_BUTTON_3 = button_array[3] ;
PUSH_BUTTON_4 = button_array[4] ;
PUSH_BUTTON_5 = button_array[5] ;
PUSH_BUTTON_6 = button_array[6] ;



if ( PUSH_BUTTON_0 == 1 )
{
led_array[0] = 0;
}
if ( PUSH_BUTTON_1 == 1 )
{
led_array[1] = 1;
}
if ( PUSH_BUTTON_2 == 1 )
{
led_array[2] = 0;
}
if ( PUSH_BUTTON_3 == 1 )
{
led_array[3] = 1;
}
if ( PUSH_BUTTON_4 == 1 )
{
led_array[4] = 0;
}
if ( PUSH_BUTTON_5 == 1 )
{
led_array[5] = 0;
}
if ( PUSH_BUTTON_6 == 1 )
{
led_array[6] = 1;
}

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: There isn't anything in that program which actually loops. It'll just execute once and exit.

Answer (score 3):

You need an enclosing while loop to keep your program executing.  Without it your code will execute and the chip will essentially reset as the program counter wraps back around to the start of code.  That's why your LEDs turn off just for a short time because your code begins to execute from the beginning again where they all get turned back on.